# doctrine orWhere inside andWhere

Tags: php, search, doctrine-orm, doctrine, where-clause

how can I use doctrine to specify search for multiple column?

```
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->where($criteria->expr()->eq('id', $id))
            ->andWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('active', true));

        $search = "Abc";
        if (!empty($search)) {
            $criteria->andWhere(
                $criteria->expr()->contains('column1', $search) || 
                $criteria->expr()->contains('column2', $search)
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `orX()`:

```
        $criteria->andWhere(
            $criteria->expr()->orX(
                $criteria->expr()->contains('column1', $search),
                $criteria->expr()->contains('column2', $search)
            )
        );
```